# Compile files from folder to folder

Tags: webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

Default application config for Laravel - Mix:

> `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js'); //default`

From what I understand, if I'm using a frontend framework, I will have to `require` and `import` framework dependency and component in `resource/js/app.js` file. Then everything left to do is use the compiled `public/app.js` at where needed.

This comes to a confusion where not every page use **all** declared components. So modulizing appears to be a reasonable choice:

```
mix.js('resources/js/ComponentA.js', 'public/js'); 
mix.js('resources/js/ComponentB.js', 'public/js'); 
mix.js('resources/js/ComponentC.js', 'public/js'); 
...
```

So I can only include compnents that are needed for a page, thus reduce file size and redundance.

This could be demoralising, especially when there're many customized components. I've tried using both solutions described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590340/webpack-compile-all-files-in-a-folder), none worked.

```
mix.js('resources/js/*.js', 'public/js'); //this one only compile the first asset
```

---

```
getFiles('resources/js').forEach(function (filepath) {
    mix.js('public/js/' + filepath, 'js');
}); //The code generator has deoptimised the styling as it exceeds the max of 500KB
```

So the question is: **Is there anyway to automatically compile files from a folder, to another folder?**